# Update specific value in array of objects in state using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to update `checked` property in list of `todos` array whenever an item is checked.

How do I update a specific item at that particular index.

For example,

```
[{name: 'todo1', checked: false},{name: 'todo2', checked: false}]
```

When I checked `todo2`, the updated array should be

```
[{name: 'todo1', checked: false},{name: 'todo2', checked: true}]
```

**Code**

```
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const handleChange = (event, index) => {
    console.log("index", index);
    setChecked(event.target.checked);
  };
  console.log(todos);
  return (
    <>
      {todos.map(
        (item, index) =>
          item.name && (
            <div key={index}>
              <Checkbox onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, index)} />
              {item.name}
            </div>
          )
      )}
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          todo: ""
        }}
        onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) => {
          setTodos([...todos, { name: values.todo, checked: checked }]);
          resetForm({ values: "" });
        }}
      >
        <Form>
          <label htmlFor="todo"></label>
          <Field id="todo" name="todo" placeholder="item" />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    </>
  );
}
```

I created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-lederberg-0dytn?file=/src/App.js). Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can toggle the checked value.

```js
const handleChange = (event, index) => {
    console.log("index", index);
    let temp = [...todos];
    temp[index]["checked"] = !temp[index]["checked"];
    setChecked(temp);
    console.log(todos);
  };
```

Output:

[image: Screenshot]

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-tereshkova-w4vfn?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: This is great!!

Comment: Glad it helped, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

here is the best way to do it with good practice on immutable state :

```
const handleChange = (event, index) => {
   const updatedTodos = todos.map((todo, todoIndex) => index === todoIndex ? {...todo, checked: true} : todo )
   setState(updatedTodos)
};
```